# accessing jsondataa sent from php

Tags: php, jquery

i have this json data being sent from my php:

```
echo json_encode(
            array(
            "Doctitle" => htmlentities($Doctitle),
            //"doctype" => htmlentities($doctype),

            )
        );
```

I hm trying to get the value displayed in jquery like so :

```
 $.post($("#add_title").attr("action"), $("#add_title").serialize(),
      function(data) {
          var fileI= data;
      var fileInput2= fileI[0].Doctitle; 
.......});
```

But all i get is undefined.and when i only check the  fileI variable, there is a string:

```
{"Doctitle":"sssvvv"}
```

how can I get the value sssvvv from this??

Comment: Read the docs, `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`, note that the last argument is the dataType, set that to `"json"`, and you're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is supposed to be able to guess the content type; but for best practice, your PHP script should clearly indicate the content type (do this before *any* output):

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

You can then access your data in javascript:

```
$.post($("#add_title").attr("action"), $("#add_title").serialize(),
    function(data) {
        var Doctitle = data.Doctitle;
    }
);
```

Comment: my php script also has ohter data that is not json.and that header seems to bring everything to a stand still

Comment: sorry it just worked right now .i placed it just above the echo json_encode statement.all the other outputs are below this .thanks.+2 for your chinese speed